# ЧПУ и 301 редирект в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, редирект, чпу

Ситуация, на сайте есть ряд страниц catalog.php, list.php, description.php (список разделов каталога, продукция и карточка товара соответственно), сделали ЧПУ через .htaccess вот так:

```
RewriteRule ^sections/(([0-9]+)/)?$ catalog.php?id=$2%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products/(([0-9]+)/)?$ list.php?id=$2%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^product/(([0-9]+)/)?$ description.php?id=$2%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

но как оказалось позже, старые адреса уже проиндексировались и нужно сделать 301 редирект на новые. Добавили правила выше:

```
RewriteCond    %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9])$
RewriteRule ^catalog\.php$ /sections/%1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^list\.php\?id=([0-9]+)$ /products/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^description\.php\?id=([0-9]+)$ /product/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

в результате - циклическая переадресация. Попытались добавить доп.параметры htaccess=Y в первое правило и ещё одно условие RewriteCond. Получилось так:

```
RewriteCond    %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9])$
RewriteCond    %{QUERY_STRING} !htaccess=Y
RewriteRule ^catalog\.php$ /sections/%1/? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^list\.php\?id=([0-9]+)$ /products/$1/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^description\.php\?id=([0-9]+)$ /product/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sections/(([0-9]+)/)?$ catalog.php?id=$2&htaccess=Y%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products/(([0-9]+)/)?$ list.php?id=$2&htaccess=Y%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^product/(([0-9]+)/)?$ description.php?id=$2&htaccess=Y%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]
```

циклической адресации не происходит, но редирект работает только для catalog.php. Дублирование RewriteCond переда каждым правилом редиректа не помогает. Как решить это средствами .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сложно сказать, где именно вы ошиблись при копировании.
Вот немного оптимизированный рабочий вариант:

```
RewriteEngine  On
RewriteCond    %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteCond    %{QUERY_STRING} !htaccess=Y
RewriteRule    ^catalog\.php$  /sections/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond    %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteCond    %{QUERY_STRING} !htaccess=Y
RewriteRule    ^list\.php$     /products/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond    %{QUERY_STRING}    ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteCond    %{QUERY_STRING}    !htaccess=Y
RewriteRule    ^description\.php$ /product/%1/? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule    ^sections/((\d+)/)?$ catalog.php?id=$2&htaccess=Y [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^products/((\d+)/)?$ list.php?id=$2&htaccess=Y [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule    ^product/((\d+)/)?$  description.php?id=$2&htaccess=Y [NC,L,QSA]
```

Вместо `%{QUERY_STRING}` можно использовать флаг [`QSA`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

> `qsappend|QSA` (добавлять строку запроса)
>   Этот флаг указывает механизму преобразований на добавление а не
>   замену, строки запроса из URL к существующей, в строке подстановки.
>   Используйте это когда вы хотите добавлять дополнительные данные в
>   строку запроса с помощью директив преобразований.

Comment: да действительно были ошибки, в общем разрулили вот так:  
RewriteCond    %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$
RewriteCond    %{QUERY_STRING} !htaccess=Y

RewriteRule ^sections/(([0-9]+)/)?$ catalog.php?id=$2&htaccess=Y%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L]

Comment: для каждого правила такие условия

Comment: Если вам помог чей-то ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его верным. Или оформите свое решение в качестве ответа

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} ^$
RewriteRule ^catalog\.php\?id=([0-9]+)$ /sections/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} ^$
RewriteRule ^list\.php\?id=([0-9]+)$ /products/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} ^$
RewriteRule ^description\.php\?id=([0-9]+)$ /product/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^sections\/([0-9]+)\/$ catalog.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,E=FINISH:1]
RewriteRule ^products\/([0-9]+)\/$ list.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,E=FINISH:1]
RewriteRule ^product\/([0-9]+)\/$ description.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,E=FINISH:1]
```

Comment: Странно, у меня на Apache 2.4 ваш вариант не завелся. Может, я не учел что-то при проверке?

Comment: Уточню. `/catalog.php?id=99` правильно редиректит на `/sections/99/`, но по этому адресу 404. С моим вариантом такого не происходит. После редиректа забирается контент из `catalog.php`